# How do I make the code use the data that has been inputted by the user respond the answers to a specific server?

Tags: python

So I wanted to create kind of a program that asks for feedback by using basic variables, input and print functions. As I am a beginner programmer. But how do I make the program send the inputted answers to a specific server? This is a question for **Python**

Comment: what have you tried so far? if you wanted a _webserver_ take a look at [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) .. as-written, it's woefully unclear what you're after or have tried

Comment: I will try tornado. Thanks.

Comment: I installed the tornado module. I will try it out.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.